# Wrong result in console

Tags: angular, web

When I try to calculate `700*0.7` in my code the result gets wrong. 
Console shows `489.99999999999994` eventhough the correct result is 490. I really don't understood what the magic is this. Can anyone clarify it? Other numbers are calculated normally.
P.S. U can try this in  console chrome. [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zucgi.png)

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmqTO.png)

Comment: [Detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895757/540352)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's some floating numbers issue: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Just round the result, and it should be good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is not always 100% accurate. Use the standard Math library functions to be 100% sure of the results when dealing with floating numbers.